# "Compiler error: Invalid library file" when simulating location in Debug > Location - CoreLocation and MapKit

Tags: swift, xcode, mapkit, core-location, mkpolyline

I was attempting to test an app on the Xcode 11 simulator that used CoreLocation. I wanted to use the "Freeway Drive" location option in the simulator under *Debug > Location* to test the MapKit polyline overlay.

***Unfortunately, no line was placed on the map and "Compiler error: Invalid library file" was printed numerous times in the log.***

It does not seem to be a code problem but more of an Xcode problem. Is there any way around this? It is very difficult to test with a physical device because movement in a confined space doesn't really pick up with CoreLocation.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

just define the polyline and "push" it into your mapView:
`let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: locations, count: locations.count)
  mapView.addOverlays([polyline])`

and declare the mkMapViewDelegate's function:

```
    //MKMapViewDelegate
  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> 
 MKOverlayRenderer 

  {
     if let mapPolyline = overlay as? MKPolyline {
            let polyLineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: mapPolyline)
            polyLineRenderer.strokeColor = .darkGray
            polyLineRenderer.lineWidth = 4.0
            return polyLineRenderer
        }
        fatalError("Polyline Renderer could not be initialized" )

   }
```

It should show the polyline on the mapView. 
I have the compiler error too and try to fix it.

Best 
Dragan

Comment: Did you get any solution yet?